# ngInfinite Scroll with AngularJS - Repeat $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to essentially loop the AngularJS $Http action using ngInfinite Scroll. I have successfully got the scroll running using 1 $Http pull and loading parts of the http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php file, but I want to reload those 15 values in the file using ngInfinite Scroll and I'm not sure how I put that into the "loadMore" function. So, on initial load, pull the complete 15 values from the file. Then once I scroll down, pull it again. Thanks!

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()'>
      <div ng-repeat="x in records">
        <p>{{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.records = data.records;

      $scope.loadMore = function() {
          $http.get("http: //www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
          .success(function(data) {
              $scope.records = data.records;
          });
      }
      });
});
```

In the loadMore() function I insert the $Http request again, but it doesn't work so any help you can give is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems. The `loadMore()` function is defined within the success function of the first `$http` get. The second problem is the returned data replaces `$scope.records` rather than being added to it.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.records = data.records;
  });
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
      $http.get("http: //www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
      .success(function(data) {
          [].push.apply($scope.records, data.records);
      });
  }
});
```